# Is it possible to emit warning when I read value of unset variable?

Tags: php, debugging

How to configure PHP to emit warning when I try to read value of unset variable?

It is frequently happens when I rename variable in one place, I obtain weird result because I forgot to rename it in other place.

Comment: Find and Replace is your friend :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set error reporting to all and you will get info about any undefined variables too, for example, put this on top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Is it possible to configure php.ini? 
I set up 
display_errors = On 
error_reporting = E_ALL
But this does not help

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible elevate the level of a notice, but you could create a [custom error handling function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

You can build that handler in a way that it reacts only to "variable not set" type notices and outputs a message or sends an E-Mail or whatever.

All the other errors you could pass on to the default error handler by returning `false` in the custom error handler.